# How to pass a value to the base class function without copying?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overriding, move-semantics

```
template <typename T>
class X
{
    std::vector<T> values;

    virtual void insert(T value)
    {
        values.push_back(std::move(value));
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Y : public X<T>
{
    virtual void insert(/* const T& value */ T value) override
    {
        do_stuff(value);
        X<T>::insert(value);
    }
};
```

Here, I'm passing the values to the `X::insert` function by value then moving it to the vector so that if an exception happens, it happens outside of the insert function and thus class `X` remains in a valid state instead of having to deal with exceptions inside the insert function.

But here, class `Y` is inheriting from `X`. I want to override `X::insert`. The problem is that they have to have the same signature and thus, I have to copy it first in `Y::insert` then pass it and copy it again in `X::insert`.

Is there any way to solve this problem other than creating two insert functions, one that takes lvalues and another that takes rvalues? If no, how should the two functions (lvalue version and rvalue version) look like?

Comment: `X<T>::insert(std::move(value));` should avoid copying if `T` supports move semantics.